# Python requests not working due to Fiddler

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, fiddler, fiddler-everywhere

When I use fiddler any request using python fails, pip doesn't work either.

```bash
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to connect using `https`. Even if you manage to connect, you would need to load local SSL certificates to authenticate the connection when Fiddler is active (Fiddler provides you a [guide](https://www.telerik.com/forums/https-not-working#:%7E:text=For%20Fiddler%20Everywhere%20to%20be,then%20enable%20the%20HTTPS%20capturing.) on how to do this with a browser). To bypass all this, use the proxy fiddler is listening on and disable certificate check. For example, using requests:

```
import requests

# Default proxy for Fiddler
proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888',
           'https': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'}

print(requests.get('https://google.com', proxies=proxies, verify=False).status_code)
```

**Output**

```
200
```